# oracle - how to search for a value in all columns of all tables in each schema?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I found the [following script](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/01/06/sql-to-search-for-a-value-in-all-columns-of-all-atbles-in-an-entire-schema/) to help me find a value in all columns in all tables in specific schema that include the word 'dummy' inside:

```
variable val varchar2(10)
exec :val := 'KING'

SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR (:val, 1, 11) "Searchword",
SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 14) "Table",
SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 14) "Column"
FROM cols,
TABLE (xmlsequence (dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype ('select '
|| column_name
|| ' from '
|| table_name
|| ' where upper('
|| column_name
|| ') like upper(''%'
|| :val
|| '%'')' ).extract ('ROWSET/ROW/*') ) ) t
ORDER BY "Table"
```

It works for me great but in a specific schema there must be some result of type `blob` or `clob` because I'm getting the following error:

```
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got BLOB
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 288
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

And "Ignor" just stops all the process and doesn't give me any results.
What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: `COLS` is just a synonym for `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`.  So you could just add `where DATA_TYPE  != 'BLOB'` to the query.  You're not goingto able to search BLOB columns like this, so you might as well skip them.

Comment: You should define your question better, as you do not state what kind of solution you are looking for. Do you want to search in BLOBS? What about dates and numbers?

Comment: Do as APC says and skip BLOBs, but I think to avoid unnecessary matches (like on NUMBER cols) you should a "DATA_TYPE IN ('VARCHAR2','CHAR', etc)" condition. If you really want to search blobs for a text (e.g. if the BLOB contains PDF or DOC types) take a look at CTXSYS, but you will need to make sure the generated query forks to this for BLOBs and does the normal matching for text. CTXSYS also requires creation of indexes so, there is a cost, but it does work.

Comment: Hey APC, I really tried to add the where DATA_TYPE != 'BLOB' inside the getxmltype but it keeps telling me that there's missing right parenthesis I'm probably got the syntax incorrect, can you please please post an answer with the full syntax? thanks so much for the trouble!